# How to pass array of tables from client to webapi and get it as dataset

Tags: .net, angularjs, dataset

anyone know how to do the following:
client:

```
this.editFileAndSave = function (tablesRaw) {
    return $http.put(uploadUrl, {
        params: { newDS: tablesRaw }
    })
}
```

Server(web api):

```
[HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage SaveFile(DataSet newDS)
```

when i try this it get to the SaveFile function but with null.

i need to send array of arrays to the server and there to get it as dataset.

any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send it as `JSON` and get it as `JSON`.
Or if you want to get `DataSet` exact in the method, you must write **Custom Model Binder**.
See this: [Custom Model Binding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder)